# Attempting to verify disabled text with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am attempting to verifyText of a text box programmatically populated then is disabled from user editing. Firebug gets me to this code.

```
<div class="flexitem-center">
    <input class="input-default" type="text" disabled="" value="20140201"/>
```

I can locate the text box but I can't figure out how to verify against the value attribute. I am fairly new to Selenium and only use the IDE not web driver.
I have found guru99.com  "How to use Locators in Selenium IDE" to be real helpful, but I could not find and answer for this. The same goes with seleniumhq.org/docs/ 
I haven't found any examples of verifying the value attribute. Maybe I can't get there from here?
My most recent attempt is

```
<td>verifyText</td>
<td>css=input.input-default[value=20140201]</td>
<td>20140201</td>
```

That generates an error - Actual value " did not match '20140201'

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you can find an element by locator = css=input.input-default[value=20140201] you are already sure that the input with such value exists (because it is included to locator). So you can do:

```
click | css=input.input-default[value=20140201]
```

And it will fail if there will be no element with such value

Secondly value is not the same thing as text. Value is an attribute of input. If you need to verify attribute value just do it:

```
verifyAttribute | css=input.input-default[value=20140201]@value | 20140201
```

Comment: The guidance in the comment block said to avoid comments like +1 or "thanks".  It just seems wrong to have someone help you and not say Thanks.